# ES6 compilation console error

Tags: ecmascript-6, gulp

I have the following gulp file:

```
'use strict'

const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');


// Create an es6 task
gulp.task('es6', () => {
    // Return gulp.src with the src set to our src folder
    // we return here do that we indicate to gulp that this task is async
    return gulp.src('src/*.js')
        // We pipe the source into babel
        .pipe(babel({
            // We need to tell babel to use the babel-preset-es2015
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        // We then pipe that into gulp.dest to set a final destination
        // In this case a build folder
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['es6'],() => {
    gulp.watch('src/*.js',['es6'])
});
```

when I run gulp it compiles correctly with no errors, however I get this error in the console whe previewing the HTML:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

referring to this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
```

How can this be solved?

**UPDATED**

I have updated my gulp file but it's not quite working yet:

```
'use strict'

const gulp = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const browserify = require('browserify');

// Create an es6 task
gulp.task('es6', () => {
    // Return gulp.src with the src set to our src folder
    // we return here do that we indicate to gulp that this task is async
    // return gulp.src('src/*.js')
    //  // We pipe the source into babel
    //  .pipe(babel({
    //      // We need to tell babel to use the babel-preset-es2015
    //      presets: ['es2015']
    //  }))
    //  // We then pipe that into gulp.dest to set a final destination
    //  // In this case a build folder
    //  .pipe(concat('src/*.js'))
    //  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));

    return browserify('src/app.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bulid/app.js'))
        .pipe(babel({
            // We need to tell babel to use the babel-preset-es2015
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['es6'],() => {
    gulp.watch('src/*.js',['es6'])
});
```

Comment: this is  babel issue, you are just trying to run CommonJS code (transpiled from ES6 export) in the browser without preparation. CommonJS doesn't run on the browser, you need to use a tool to package it for the browser, such as Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: You need webpack/browserfy *after* transpilation happening

Comment: I have updated but getting the following error: events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Streaming not supported